# Proof on Diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

**What I am given**

Definition 1: A endomorphism $F \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ is called *diagonalizable* iff a basis consisting of eigenvectors ('eigenbasis') exists.

Definition 2: A matrix A is called diagonalizable iff the endomorphism $F(x) = Ax$ is diagonalizable.

Lemma 1: The columns of $S$ (mentioned below) are a eigenbasis.

**Question**

> Prove that if $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is a eigenbasis, $A$ is diagonizable iff the invertible matrix $S = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ satisfies $S^{-1} A S = diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

**My idea:**
I will show $A S = S diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$.
We have
$$
A S
= A (v_1 \ldots v_n)
          = (\lambda_1 v_1 \ldots \lambda_n v_n)
          = (v_1 \ldots v_n) (\lambda_1 \ldots \lambda_n)
          = S \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 & & 0 \\
        & \ddots & \\
        0 & & \lambda_n
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$
I am pretty sure the third equality doesn't hold because that only works if (v_1 \ldots v_n) only has elements on it's diagonal.

Comment: What issues are you having with the question? Lemma 1 looks like it does all the hard work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand the question. If $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ is an eigenbasis, then $A$ is diagonizable by definition.

Comment: The questions asked if the matrix is diagonizable, and the definition of diagonizable matrix is that the corresponding endomorphism is diagonaziable. We want to show that the eigenbasis-matrix $S$ satisfies $A S = S$ diag $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Think about the first column of that last product. It gives you $\lambda_1$ times the first column of $S$, which is $\lambda_1v_1$. What about the second column? It gives you $\lambda_2$ times the second column of $S$, which is $\lambda_2v_2$. And so on ...